Socket Server Multithreading Java NIO
i need help to create a multithreaded java socket server that can handle and process the request asynchronously.
What i did right now is i created java NIO Socket Server and Client, the client will send request simultaneously, to test the asynchronous mechanism on the server, the second request thread will be distrupted by a thread sleep.
Expected Result: the Third to Five request will be processed asynchronously without waiting second request is completed.
Current Result: the Third to Five request is not processed before the second request thread sleep is completed.
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class NIOServer {
    private static Selector selector = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try {
            selector = Selector.open();
            // We have to set connection host,port and
            // non-blocking mode
            ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel
                    = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            ServerSocket serverSocket
                    = serverSocketChannel.socket();
            serverSocket.bind(
                    new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8089));
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            int ops = serverSocketChannel.validOps();
            serverSocketChannel.register(selector, ops,
                    null);
            while (true) {
                selector.select();
                Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys
                        = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> i
                        = selectedKeys.iterator();

                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = i.next();

                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        // New client has been accepted
                        handleAccept(serverSocketChannel,
                                key);
                    }
                    else if (key.isReadable()) {
                        // We can run non-blocking operation
                        // READ on our client
                        handleRead(key);
                    }
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void
    handleAccept(ServerSocketChannel mySocket,
                 SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {

        System.out.println("Connection Accepted..");

        // Accept the connection and set non-blocking mode
        SocketChannel client = mySocket.accept();
        client.configureBlocking(false);

        // Register that client is reading this channel
        client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    private static void handleRead(SelectionKey key)
            throws IOException
    {
//        System.out.println("Reading client's message.");

        // create a ServerSocketChannel to read the request
        SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel)key.channel();

        // Create buffer to read data
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

        client.read(buffer);

        // Parse data from buffer to String
        String data = new String(buffer.array()).trim();
        if (data.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + data);

            System.out.println(new Date());

            if (data.equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "Hello, server! Request 2")) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                    System.out.println("Sleep is executed");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            if (data.equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "Testing5")) {
                client.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed...");
            }
        }
    }
}

Do you guys have any advice how to handle this mechanism?
Thank you

The issue you're experiencing is due to the fact that the handleRead method is being executed on the same thread that manages the NIO selector. When one request is being processed, the selector cannot handle other requests until the current one is completed. This is why your third to fifth requests are blocked until the second request finishes sleeping.
To fix this, you need to process the requests in separate threads. This will allow other requests to be handled asynchronously while a particular request is being processed. You can achieve this by using a thread pool to handle the processing of each request in a separate thread.
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class NIOServer {
    private static Selector selector = null;
    private static ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            selector = Selector.open();
            ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            ServerSocket serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8089));
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            int ops = serverSocketChannel.validOps();
            serverSocketChannel.register(selector, ops, null);

            while (true) {
                selector.select();
                Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> i = selectedKeys.iterator();

                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = i.next();

                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        handleAccept(serverSocketChannel, key);
                    } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                        // Submit the task to the thread pool for asynchronous processing
                        threadPool.submit(() -> {
                            try {
                                handleRead(key);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (threadPool != null && !threadPool.isShutdown()) {
                threadPool.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void handleAccept(ServerSocketChannel mySocket, SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Connection Accepted..");

        SocketChannel client = mySocket.accept();
        client.configureBlocking(false);

        client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    private static void handleRead(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

        client.read(buffer);

        String data = new String(buffer.array()).trim();
        if (data.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + data);
            System.out.println(new Date());

            if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello, server! Request 2")) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                    System.out.println("Sleep is executed");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("Testing5")) {
                client.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed...");
            }
        }
    }
}


Hi thank you for your advice, I tried your code, the second request still block the remaining messages, is there any alternative like how to not block the remaining request? Thank you

If the second request is still blocking the remaining messages, this suggests that even though the request handling is offloaded to a separate thread, the non-blocking nature of NIO and how the data is being processed might still cause delays. Here’s an alternative approach using a SelectionKey attachment to associate a specific task (such as reading or writing) with each key, and then delegating long-running tasks to a separate thread.

Do you have any sample of the implementation of it?

@mcser be aware that this answer and comment reads very much like it was generated by an LLM, such as ChatGPT. Which is explicitly not allowed

Java docs is your best friend try to read about the SelectionKey and put the read and write request in separate threads

serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
and in handleread function try to this like this
threadPool.submit(() -> processRequest(key, message));
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html
check the function isreadable() or iswriteable() to send the read request in readthread and write request into write function

when should i register the channel with OP_ACCEPT? also you tell me to put thread pool inside the threadpool?

serverSocketChannel.register(selector, ops, null); simply replace it. yeah read and write request should be in separate thread to get required behaviour that you want too. i can't write for you the complete code

Hi @Muhammad_08 i've been experimenting with your ideas but it still doesn't work correctly, i built a repository to do the experiment https://github.com/chad1st/SocketApp/tree/multithreading, the class of the server is NioSelectorEchoServer that i've been trying to use for multithreading. Thank you
